# how to update linux headers properly in ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages

we have given our servers to security check and then they have suggested the below.

- Installed package : linux-headers-5.4.0-29_5.4.0-29.33 Fixed package : linux-headers-5.4.0-_5.4.0-105.119
- Installed package : linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33 Fixed package : linux-headers-5.4.0--generic_5.4.0-105.119
- Installed package : linux-image-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33 Fixed package : linux-image-5.4.0--generic_5.4.0-105.119
- Installed package : linux-modules-5.4.0-29-generic_5.4.0-29.33 Fixed package : linux-modules-5.4.0--ge

How to update this particular packages properly without effecting the server as many are of the production servers.

I tried sudo apt-get update -y(Did not workout)

Also tried

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.4.0-_5.4.0-105.119
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.4.0-_5.4.0-105.119
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.4.0-_5.4.0-105.119'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.4.0-_5.4.0-105.119'
```

Not able to understand how to update the packages.

Comment: use apt search  linux-header to find wich linux header are avaible

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to update them:

1. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y --upgrade linux-headers-5.4.0-105 linux-headers-5.4.0-105-generic linux-image-5.4.0-105-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-105-generic` (remember to add the focal-updates repo).
2. Compile them from source code. Download the latest source (5.4.0 LTS branch) from https://cdn.kernel.org. Extract the file, run make menuconfig, configure it, run make deb-pkg, wait some time, and then in the parent directory you'll find the .deb files. You will probably need to install many dependencies, so it's a slow process.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response Lumito. What does it mean by "remember to add the focal-updates repo" , can you give an example?